# Create a spreadsheet with multiple pivoted tabs using Pandas

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

The following code successfully creates a spreadsheet from a pivot table:

```
pivot_table_name.to_excel('spreadsheet_file_name.xlsx')
```

But now I need to be able to create more than one tab.  Other posts have recommended using code like this:

```
for row in dataframe_to_rows('table_name', index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(row)
```

But that is for a "normal" table/dataframe, i.e. not pivoted so if I try that I will of course get the expected:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Is there a way to do this using Pandas?

Also, in case is helpful in any way, I am currently using Papermill to execute multiple scripts so if separate processing is required that is not a problem.  Not everything needs to happen in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add multiple sheets in the same workbook this should work.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('spreadsheet_file_name.xlsx') as writer:  
    pivot_table_name.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    pivot_table_name2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```